# Why Java is running faster than C here?

Tags: java, c, performance

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859790/look-what-my-machine-can-do-in-1-second),

<sub>Now visible only for users with > 10k rep</sub>

I came up with the following code:

```
$cat loop.c 
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while( i++ < 2147483647 );
}

$cc -o loop loop.c  

$ time ./loop
real 0m11.161s
user 0m10.393s
sys 0m0.012s


$cat Loop.java 
class Loop {
    public static void main( String [] args ) { 
        int i = 0;
        while( i++ < 2147483647 );
    }
}

$javac Loop.java 

$time java  Loop  
real 0m4.578s
user 0m3.980s
sys 0m0.048s
```

Why does the Java version runs almost 3x faster than the C version?  What I'm missing here?

This is run on Ubuntu 9.04 with:

Intel(R) Pentium(R) M @ 1.73GHz

32 bits

**EDIT**

This is amazing. Using the -O3 option in C optimize the loop and using -server in Java does the same.  This are the "optimized times".
[image: optimized]

Comment: You should also run java with the `-server` option to make it faster. And of course, like others have pointed out, use the `-O3` option in the `cc` command.

Comment: Just for the record, I saw the optimization flag for C, but I thought it was "03" when it really should be "O3"  ;)

Comment: @dehmann OMG with -server java goes from 4s to 7ms :-o :-O :-O

Comment: Can I have your Ubuntu settings/theme?

Comment: @Baddie: Sure.. erhmm... how do I tell you that?

Comment: @Baddie & @Oscar ... Dito on the theme, that's really nice.

Comment: @Mark: I don't remember have set a theme .. I think I just put a background I liked, drag and drop the tool bar to the left and customize it to look translucent.. Mmmhh what else... I'll check it out and let you know.

Comment: @Oscar & @Baddie The theme base your using is called dust, it's a default install in Ubuntu. It seems that you've changed the default text decoration on the menu bar from bold to normal. And yes, the menu bar is now on the left.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I expect `javac` is defaulting to some higher level of optimization than your C compiler.  When I compile with `-O3` here, the C is way faster:

C with `-O3`:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Your java program:

```
real    0m0.294s
user    0m0.269s
sys     0m0.051s
```

Some more details; without optimization, the C compiles to:

```
0000000100000f18 pushq %rbp
0000000100000f19 movq %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000f1c movl %edi,0xec(%rbp)
0000000100000f1f movq %rsi,0xe0(%rbp)
0000000100000f23 movl $0x00000000,0xfc(%rbp)
0000000100000f2a incl 0xfc(%rbp)
0000000100000f2d movl $0x80000000,%eax
0000000100000f32 cmpl %eax,0xfc(%rbp)
0000000100000f35 jne  0x00000f2a
0000000100000f37 movl $0x00000000,%eax
0000000100000f3c leave
0000000100000f3d ret
```

With optimization (`-O3`), it looks like this:

```
0000000100000f30 pushq %rbp
0000000100000f31 movq %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000f34 xorl %eax,%eax
0000000100000f36 leave
0000000100000f37 ret
```

As you can see, the entire loop has been removed.  `javap -c Loop` gave me this output for the java bytecode:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   iinc    1, 1
   6:   ldc #2; //int 2147483647
   8:   if_icmpge   14
   11:  goto    2
   14:  return

}
```

It appears the loop is compiled in, I guess something happens at runtime to speed that one up. (As others have mentioned, the JIT compiler squashes out the loop.)

Comment: Your compiler has probably optimised the loop clear out of existence. Check the generated assembly code.

Comment: I would expect so, yeah.  I'm sure the java does the same, the time involved is the JVM startup.  If I stick a `volatile` in the C program it goes back to slow; I don't know how to do the same in java.

Comment: Way lot better. I saw that flag but I thought It was "zero three" and I couldn't apply it. Until I saw this answer i realize it was "Ouh three"  new time: "real: 0m0.001s, user:0m0.000s, sys:0m0.000s"

Comment: @tur1ng, I tried that, it gives me an error compiling.  I don't know java from a hole in the ground, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Oscar, one of the best things you can do to improve your programming life is to find a fixed-width font that makes it easy to tell the difference between `O` and `0`, and between `1`, `l`, and `I`.

Comment: @Carl Norum: java disassempler is javap, so run javap -c Loop. Java does not remove code upon compilation, but probably optimizes it with JIT.

Comment: @dahmann: Not really, it is pretty slow, the cc optimizer is the one that mekes a good job here. @Carl. Well I guess this time it wasn't the font but PEBKAC http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/2310/screenshot3xo.png

Comment: @Piligrim, yup, that's how it appears.

Comment: It looks like ( as dehmann points out ) the `-server` option performs way lot better.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, I don't see any difference with or without -server. It gives performance boost only for long-running applications.

Comment: @Piligrim: I updated the question with the performance obtained by using the -server flag. I don't know how it works though but my guess is that it uses a different algorithm to optimize this.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes, -server makes the JIT to compile all the code, not just hot spots. On my machine the time is 0.165 in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that the JIT is optimizing away the empty loop.

Update: The Java Performance Tuning article [Followup to Empty Loop Benchmark](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm029.shtml) seems to support that, along with the other answers here that point out that the C code needs to also be optimized in order to make a meaningful comparison.  Key quote:

> Had I chosen to use the client mode 1.4.1 JVM (client is the default mode), the loops would not be optimized away. Had I chosen to use Microsoft's C++ compiler, the C version would take no time. Clearly, the choice of compiler is critical.

Answer (score 5):

There are some things you need to control for here:

- the startup of the JVM is nontrivial compared to startup of a compiled C program
- your loop isn't doing anything, and the compiler probably knows that
- JIT compilers often produce better code than a non-optimised C compiler

Answer (score 5):

"What I'm missing here?" Optimization flags.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this question really has an answer; it depends on the optimizations both compilers perform.  In this case I expect either, if poked into sufficient optimization effort, would eliminate the loop entirely as `i` is never used.

Answer (score 4):

[Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) - you are at least missing the `-O2` flag on the `gcc` command line.

Answer (score 2):

The Java JIT compiler is smart enough to optimize the loop away, while your C compiler seems to have most of the optimizations turned off.

So you are really comparing the time to start up the Java machine with the time it takes unoptimized C code to count to 2 billion.

Answer (score 2):

#### Because the program doesn't do anything, an optimizer can remove the loop

---

If you are trying to make a compiler do a certain unit or, well, *benchmark* of work, then you need to fool it into thinking the result of the work will actually be used.

One way to do this is to write a function in one file, compile it, and then call it with the setup from another file. No compiler can anticipate what will be compiled in the future.

Without that, it's just sort of a contest between default optimization levels and has no useful significance.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does absolutely nothing so this says nothing about the performance of both languages. The only thing it tells you is if your compiler is able to figure this out and therefore completely skips your program.

To make it do "something" you would have to print every increment to stdout. If you print only the end result a good compiler could optimize your program to a statement that just prints this result and skips the whole "computation".

Comment: At least it tells me how long would it take to skip the whole thing ( and if it can skip it in fist place. For C would take 3ms for Java 200ms  and the answer is that both can skip it.