# Is it possible to get a Java program faster than the same program (optimized) in C?

Tags: java, c++, c, optimization

Regarding the fact that C/C++ optimization are produced at compilation time, and Java optimizations are produced at runtime. Is it possible to get a Java program faster than the same program (optimized) in C?

I understand that runtime optimizations can be better than compilation time. Hence I am wondering if the gain of these optimization can be compared to the overhead of running the JVM.

Comment: With today's processors there's hardly any need to optimize..focus on your business logic..you can later optimize your code if that's really needed

Comment: Easy. Compare a well implemented Java data structure with a naive (but compiled with optimization) C equivalent.

Comment: I just want to mention that I were not asking for code nor is an specific coding problem. I know that I can write a program in Java which runs faster than the same program in C++ (Not Optimized) e.g. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260157/why-java-is-running-faster-than-c-here). But I cannot figure out how to make a program in Java faster than its version (optimized) in C++. @Rekin and @Cyan draws insights about my question, But I would like to leave it open for a  while, or someone shows JVM runtime optimizations which are not applicable when compiling the C++ code, i.e. `gcc -O3`.

Answer (score 10):

In theory, yes.
In practice, it is highly unlikely.

One of the fundamental assumption is that C/C++ is compiled once for a binary opcode target, and that Java is compiled for the specific machine it is running on. This should give an edge to Java. But the reality is that even C/C++ can have several optimization path, dynamically selected at run time, and get most of the benefit of specific-target compilation.

Conversely, as stated by Rekin, the Java JVM needs to dynamically profile the Java program to know what to optimize and how. Profiling is an expensive operation in itself, and that overhead can't be taken off Java JVM. On the other hand, selecting the right set of optimization for the current workload can give an edge. In practice, most C programs (but not all :) are well tuned for their task, and there is little left to optimize using profiling techniques.

There are other effects in Java which completely dwarf these compilation issues. Probably at first position is the Garbage Collector.

Garbage collector first mission is to ease programming, take care of, and avoiding one of the most nasty recurrent bug of C/C++, memory leaks. This feature alone justify the large use of Java in many industrial environment.

However, it has a cost. A very large one. According to studies, it is necessary to have available about 5x the amount of strictly necessary memory to make sure garbage collector works with minimal overhead. So, whenever such amount of memory is lacking, GC overhead starts to become significant, putting performance to a crawl.

Adversely, it may happen, in some circumstances, that freeing the algorithm of memory allocation charge may allow to *change the algorithm*, and adopt a better, faster one. In such a circumstance, Java can get the edge, and be faster than a C program.

But as you can guess, this is uncommon...

Comment: I once read, that there are some very aggressive optimizations the JVM can make. The end result is high-performing machine code. So, once it gets there it can compete. The thing is: to know what and when to compile a hot-spots need to be determined. That implies constant profiling. That's a significant overhead, but it gets worse: the algorithms which determine if the optimization is feasible has Big-Oh O(N^2) or even O(N^3) complexity. I read it from a blog of a JVM Engineer. See if I can find the source...

Comment: Keep in mind that just _finding_ the hotspots is already a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: "According to studies, it is necessary to have available about 5x the amount of strictly necessary memory to make sure garbage collector works with minimal overhead." there was only *one* such study [1]  and it was not using state-of-the-art JVM like the one from Oracle and state-of-the-art GCs but a *simulation* instead. This paper contradicts empirical experience - many applications run with no noticeable GC overhead with only as little as 1.5x the live memory. Considering manual C++ allocators have some fragmentation as well, that's not something I'd call a "large cost".

Comment: [1] https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf

Comment: O(N^3) complexity matters only if n is large. Many of the optimization algorithms work with very small "N"s, because N is often a number of variables or branches per method call, etc.

Comment: That's a very good point Piotr. GC cost should be better evaluated.
There are unfortunately not a lot more reasons to believe a manufacturer's claim with commercial interest at stake than a .edu study with limited tooling. I'm afraid that this issue might turn political to some, and I guess that it's relatively simple to create a scenario which is relatively friendly, or relatively nasty, to GC performance.

Therefore, with limited trustable information source, maybe we could just use the careful words "GC needs more memory than strictly necessary to work properly".

Answer (score 2):

The fact that C/C++ programs are specifically written for a specific platform and directly compiled into machine code, they are bound to be more closer to the software/hardware platform they are running. Hence they would be faster.

Java optimization is built into JVM and best optimization (in terms of how fast program would be executed) is achieved with just in time (JIT) way of processing bytecode. Though JIT proved to be more memory intensive.

So, comparing these strategy clearly shows that C/C++ native code would be faster; as JVM still have some overhead to convert bytecode into native even with JIT.

But this is the price paid for platform in dependency and java being more portable.

Taken from [when is java faster than c++ (or when is JIT faster then precompiled)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516778/when-is-java-faster-than-c-or-when-is-jit-faster-then-precompiled), I found some of the scenario's when Java execution could outperform C/C++

> Lots of little memory allocations/deallocations. The major JVMs have
> extremely efficient memory subsystems, and garbage collection can be
> more efficient than requiring explicit freeing (plus it can shift
> memory addresses and such if it really wants to).
>
> Efficient access through deep hierarchies of method calls. The JVM is
> very good at eliding anything that is not necessary, usually better in
> my experience than most C++ compilers (including gcc and icc). In part
> this is because it can do dynamic analysis at runtime (i.e. it can
> overoptimize and only deoptimize if it detects a problem).
>
> Encapsulation of functionality into small short-lived objects.

Comment: +1 The JVM tends to be better at optimising away code which does do anything useful.  Having access to dynamic compilation means it can optimise based on things only know at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead of the JVM is huge. It has to load several classes, which live inside zip (jar) files and need to be extracted.

For every class loaded, some static analysis methods will be run on it, to see if there is unreachable code, operand stack type problems and other things.

Then, a profiler runs all the time to decide which parts of code are worth optimize, and usually this means that those methods need to be called a few thousand of times before they are optimized.

Besides all that, you also get the garbage collector.

I can't really imagine a properly written C program, compiled for the platform it's running on, being outperformed by a Java equivalent. Perhaps only if you hit some rare corner-case where the JVM has some optimization and the C compiler doesn't have that specific optimization implemented.

Comment: You first paragraph is mainly relevant if somebody tried to write  programs running for a fraction of second (like e.g. `/bin/ls`) in Java. A typical server runs for days or years, so what....

Answer (score 1):

Where I have seen Java run faster than C is when there is limited resources and time to market is more important.  In this situation, you don't have as much time to write the code as efficiently as you could as in C and C++ you can end up doing things which are less efficient than what the JVM does for you. i.e. if you need the sort of things the JVM does already, it can be faster.

If you have a machines with enough resources, the developer time is more expensive/critical and you can end up with a working, stable system in less time and have time to profile/optimise while a C team might still be fixing all the core dumps.  Your mileage will vary.

For resources limited devices, C still dominates because you have control over resource allocation.  BTW Most mobile phone now run Java (or objective-C) fine.